# What is a DDL script in the context of databases?

Tags: script, database

What is a DDL script in the context of databases?

Comment: Needs more explanation.

Answer (score 20):

DDL = Data Definition Language

From the **[Wikipedia entry for DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language)**:

> A Data Definition Language (DDL) is a
>   computer language for defining data
>   structures. The term was first
>   introduced in relation to the Codasyl
>   database model, where the schema of
>   the database was written in a Data
>   Definition Language describing the
>   records, fields, and "sets" making up
>   the user Data Model. Initially it
>   referred to a subset of SQL, but is
>   now used in a generic sense to refer
>   to any formal language for describing
>   data or information structures, like
>   XML schemas.

So, for databases, a DDL script is a script that creates the structure (tables, columns, indexes, ...) of a database.

Answer (score 0):

DDL - **Data Definition Language**

Commonly, it consists of some SQL statements to create schemas and tables with their inter-relationships, i.e. foreign key constraints.

You can use this script when you need to install new system on client side. No need to create tables one by one. These types of scripts are contained within files with ".sql" extension. You just need to open your data base management software (ex-MySql Workbench) and import the file or copy-paste the script to the script editing area and run it.

Comment: Can you expand on this?